# How to display Arabic letters when importing html data into Excel?

Tags: html, excel, vba, character-encoding

I read a question here about converting html into Excel and it works but with unsolved issue. If the html contains Arabic letters, as it not displayed correctly in Excel after the import.

- The code the I copied to do the import is below
- I tried to fix the charset issue using the below code but I had runtime error
  `HTML_Content.Charset = "utf-8"` (in the below section 'Create HTMLFile Object)

```vb
Sub HTML_Table_To_Excel()

    Dim htm As Object
    Dim Tr As Object
    Dim Td As Object
    Dim Tab1 As Object
    Dim file As String

    'Replace the file path with your own
    file = "c:\your_File.html"

    'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function
    TextFile = FreeFile

    'Open the text file
    Open file For Input As TextFile

    'Create HTMLFile Object
    Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)

    Column_Num_To_Start = 1
    iRow = 2
    iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
    iTable = 0

    'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format
    For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")
        
        With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
            
            For Each Tr In .Rows
                
                For Each Td In Tr.Cells
                    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
                    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText
                    iCol = iCol + 1
                Next Td
                
                iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Next Tr
            
        End With

        iTable = iTable + 1
        iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
        iRow = iRow + 1
        
    Next Tab1

    MsgBox "Process Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: Including a relevant html portion using snippet tool via [edit] might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`charSet` is a read-only property. That is likely the source of your error if attempting to set via this property.

I think you might want:

```
HTML_Content.defaultCharset = "UTF-8"
```

I would prefer to declare early bound `MSHTML.HTMLDocument`, by VBE > Tools >References > Microsoft HTML Object Library reference, then something like `html.defaultCharset = "UTF-8"` where `html` is your instance of the object.

I really dislike `htmlFile` as it is so limited and only useful when you absolutely cannot add project references.

Also, please declare all your variables and use `Option Explicit` at top of modules.

Comment: Thanks for the TIP, but after trying the above the issue still exist

Comment: Can edit relevant html to your question and detail your system settings? I doubt I will be able to reproduce based on my Excel region settings as is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123782/unicode-characters-as-a-result-of-xmlhttp-request   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821687/unicode-characters-incorrect-when-parsing-json   maybe something there?    My answer should have solved your error message.